# PHP Calculating each row with column values and store in a variable

Tags: php, mysql

In this example, how to calculate in each row how many NULL values, how many zeros(0) and how many ones(1) and each values store in a variable.

```
+-------+--------+--------+--------+--------+--------+--------+--------+--------+--------+
| StdID | day1S1 | day1S2 | day1S3 | day2S1 | day2S2 | day2S3 | day3S1 | day3S2 | day3S3 |
+-------+--------+--------+--------+--------+--------+--------+--------+--------+--------+
|     3 | NULL   |      1 |      0 |      1 |      1 |      0 | NULL   |      1 |      1 |
|     4 | 1      |      1 |      0 |      1 |      0 |      0 | NULL   |      1 |      1 |
+-------+--------+--------+--------+--------+--------+--------+--------+--------+--------+
```

O/p

```
**StdID = 3**
$null = 2;
$zeros = 2;
$ones = 5;

**StdID = 4**
$null = 1;
$zeros = 3;
$ones = 5;
```

I dont know how to do this, but I am trying with the following code

```
$check = isset($day1['day1S1'])  ? "1" : "0"; doesnt work

$values = $day1['day1S1']+$day1['day1S2']+$day1['day1S3'] etc
```

Please help me to solve this. Thanks

Comment: Consider revising your schema

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> **[array_walk](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-walk.php) -  Apply a user supplied function to every member of an array**
>
> **[array_count_values](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-count-values.php) - Counts all the values of an array**

You can use `array_walk`,`array_count_values` function, for example

```
$arr = [
  'StdID' => [
    '3' => ['NULL',1,0,1,1,0,'NULL',1,1],
    '4' => [1,1,0,1,0,0,'NULL',1,1]
  ]
];
$res=[];
array_walk($arr['StdID'], function($v, $k) use (&$res){
   $res['StdID'][$k] = array_count_values($v);
});
echo '<pre>';
print_r($res);
```

output

```
Array
(
  [StdID] => Array
    (
        [3] => Array
            (
                [NULL] => 2
                [1] => 5
                [0] => 2
            )

        [4] => Array
            (
                [1] => 5
                [0] => 3
                [NULL] => 1
            )

    )

)
```

Comment: Could you please answer me some more specific?

Comment: Thanks Rakesh, code works fine. 

Only a small doubt, 
if values 0 (zero) is not in DB, it shows an error 'Undefined offset: 0'. The same way is NULL is not there it shows error. How to solve it, sorry for the disturbance Rakesh

Comment: @user2594154 the result is displaying based on the array values, if array have 0 you should get the 0 index else not